# Send email when a file is deleted to the user who had uploaded the file

Tags: document, delete, sharepoint-email

I want an email sent out when a file is deleted. The email should only be sent to the user who had initially uploaded the file to the share point folder. I know we can send an email to specific users when a file is deleted  but can we send it dynamically to the user who had uploaded the file? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could potentially achieve this:

1. Set alert with 'Items are deleted', but you will have less control over how and what.
2. If you are on SharePoint Online, you could use MS Flow to trigger on file delete.

[image]

Comment: I checked both these ways but there is no way that it picks up the email of the user who uploaded the file that was deleted.

Comment: I believe the 'Created By' is the field you need to use.

Comment: I'm only getting the deleted by option

Comment: Have a look at this: https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/05/02/microsoft-flow-new-when-a-file-or-item-is-deleted-triggers/